# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany()->getResults() ignores soft deletes

Tags: laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2.*, I have a pivot table that implements soft deletes.  When I run Model::all() I get the expected results, but when I access the data via the parent, I'm getting the deleted rows as well.

The parent model Classification has the following code:

```
 public function organizations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization', 'organization_classifications', 'classification_id', 'organization_id')->getResults();
}
```

The pivot model OrganizationClassification looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
class OrganizationClassification extends BaseCrudModel{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $table = 'organization_classifications'; 
}
```

The table has a nullable column, deleted_at, and one of 2 records has a proper datetime value in that column.

If I do OrganizationClassification::all() I get one row back, but if I do the following:

```
$c = Classification::find(1);
$ret = $c->rganizations();
```

I get 2 rows back.

Is there some way of getting back only undeleted rows, but in the mixed format that getResults provides?

Comment: I'm guessing `BaseCrudModel` extends `Eloquent`. Also what does `getResults()` do, since it's not part of the query builder API?

Comment: The API doc doesn't say much about what getResults() returns other than, "Get the results of the relationship."  It's a mixed array and pulls the row, the pivot and, maybe (I don't remember)ssociated row. And yes, BaseCrudModel extends Eloquent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the soft delete column is on the pivot table, you should try setting up a condition for that:

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organization', 'organization_classifications', 'classification_id', 'organization_id')->whereNull('organization_classifications.deleted_at');
}
```

This will exclude the entries where `deleted_at` is `null`.